# A problem with forwarding an exported function in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, proxy, export, forwarding

Hi
I am forwarding an exported function of a DLL to another function in my DLL. I use ExpX64 for editing the export table of the DLL.
(for example I forward the ?MyFunc@MyClass@@SAJJAEAUMyStruct@@@Z to myDLL.?MyFunc@MyClass@@SAJJAEAUMyStruct@@@Z)

My problem is that my target function is a member of a class and in runtime, forwarding that generates a COMException ("attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist")

What do you think I'm doing wrong? (Calling conventions? And there should be a difference between forwarding a regular function and a class-member one.)
I implement MyFunc like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) LONG MyClass::MyFunc (long a,struct MyStruct& b)
```

ps: I can also use a DLL proxy (create a proxy DLL that implements the target function I want and forward all other functions to the original DLL, but the problem that my function is part of a class, still remains)

Thanks

Comment: how do you allocate memory for the class (in which module), and how do you free it?

Comment: I don't! I use static methods (I'm forwarding the exported function to my static method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that the error you get has to do anything with the forwarding. The error is STG_E_REVERTED, and that is related to structured storage (which your method appears to be completely unrelated to). The error is apparently particularly frequent in SharePoint applications.

**Edit**: [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Microsoft API for persistence in COM.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please be more specific about "structure storage" ?

Comment: @Mehdi: See my edit (I mistyped; it's "structure*d*" storage)

Comment: Out of curiosity: what specifically was the problem?